# Getting Window Title In C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the current window's title and I am using this:

```
string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    char wnd_title[256];
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(hwnd, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
    return wnd_title;
}
```

This worked for me. Now I want to get window title of every newly opened window on runtime.
E.g if I open Google Chrome, it should then print the title of the Chrome window. After that if I open a notepad file it should print its title.

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Apply some divide and conquer to break your problem down. There is quite a lot to automatically-updating whatnots, and obtaining a full list of all accessible windows.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monitor windows which are appearing on the taskbar, you can use the `RegisterShellHookWindow` function.

If you want to monitor all windows, I believe `SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, ...)` is the way to go. See Raymond's post [Using accessibility to monitoring windows as they come and go](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx) for an implementation example.